# Select most recent record in sub child

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following tables/columns:

```
Parent:
  ParentID

Child:
  ChildID
  ParentID

SubChild:
  SubChildID
  ChildID
  Date
```

`Parent` has 1 to Many relationship with `Child`

`Child` has 1 to Many relationship with `SubChild`

For every `Parent`, I need to get the `SubChild` with the most recent `Date` value.
How can I do this using SQL. I've tried using `MAX(Date)`, 
but I can't seem to figure out how to join `Parent` and `Child` successfully.

The ideal result set would contain all the `Parent`s joined with all the `SubChild` columns of the latest record.

Note: using **MS SQL 2005+**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at using [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Something like

```
;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  p.ParentID,
                sc.SubChildID,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.ParentID ORDER BY sc.[Date] DESC) RowID
        FROM    Parent p INNER JOIN
                Child c ON  p.ParentID = c.ParentID INNER JOIN
                SubChild sc ON  c.ChildID = sc.ChildID
)
SELECT  ParentID,
        SubChildID
FROM    Vals
WHERE   RowID = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

For some data distributions this approach could be faster.

```
SELECT p.ParentID,
       sc.SubChildID,
       sc.Date
FROM   Parent p
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) s.SubChildID,
                                  s.Date
                    FROM   SubChild s
                           JOIN Child c
                             ON c.ChildID = s.ChildID
                    WHERE c.ParentID=p.ParentID
                    ORDER  BY s.Date DESC) sc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a correlated subquery, but it is faster to use the SQL Server 2005 [ranking functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx). As long as you know what you're doing, that is.

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple, you can do a sub-select.  In my testing this has the same performance as the "cross-apply" approach:

```
select firstname, lastname, 
(Select top 1 Display from _notes where _notes.ParentId = c.Id order by createdon desc) as MostRecentNote
from _contacts c
```

For 47k records, this "sub-select" approach takes about 4 seconds.  To make it fast, I added a sorted index on _Notes that included ParentId, CreatedOn (Sorted descending) and the Display column was included).  This drops the query to less than 1 second on 47k records.