# Selecting the record with most recent datetime value

Tags: sql, datetime, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I have three tables

Buildings

```
BuildingKey(int) | BuildingID(varchar) | ...
```

Areas

```
areaKey(int) | areaID(varchar) | buildingKey(int-FK[Buildings]) | ...
```

Transactions

```
transactionKey(int) | areaKey(int-FK[Areas]) | value(float) | trnDateTime(DateTime)
```

There may be several `Areas` in a `Building`.

All areas have many `Transactions`, with different `value` and different `trnDateTime`.

What I want to do is get the latest `value` (Transaction) of **each** `Area` of a `Building` (when the `buildingKey` is given).

I referred to some previous questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209391/select-most-recent-record-in-sub-child), and tried following.

(1)

```
DECLARE @buildingKey INT
SET @buildingKey = 3

;WITH Vals AS (
    SELECT  T.areaKey AS AreaKey,
            T.value AS CurrentValue, 
            T.trnDateTime AS RecordedDateTime,                
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.buildingKey ORDER BY T.trnDateTime DESC) RowID

    FROM    Buildings B INNER JOIN
            Areas A ON  B.buildingKey = A.buildingKey INNER JOIN 
            Transactions T  ON A.areaKey = T.areaKey

    WHERE B.buildingKey = @buildingKey
)
SELECT  AreaKey,
        CurrentValue,
        MAX(RecordedDateTime) AS RecentReading,
        RowID
FROM    Vals
WHERE   RowID = 1
GROUP BY AreaKey, CurrentValue, RowID
```

!) Returns the latest value (among all the Areas); **not** the latest value of **each** Area!

(2)

```
DECLARE @buildingKey INT
SET @buildingKey = 3

SELECT  A.areaKey AS AreaKey, 
        A.areaID AS AreaID,
        T.value AS CurrentValue,
        T.trnDateTime AS RecordedDateTime                   

FROM Areas A, Buildings B, Transactions T

WHERE   @buildingKey = B.buildingKey AND 
        B.buildingKey = A.buildingKey AND
        T.areaKey = A.areaKey AND
        T.trnDateTime IN (SELECT MAX(T.trnDateTime), T.areaKey
                                  FROM Transactions T
                                  GROUP BY T.areaKey)
```

!) Gives an error -->

```
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

Comment: Edited the two queries I have tried, according to the table descriptions I have given at the top. (to make them more understandable and more generic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
DECLARE @buildingKey INT
SET @buildingKey = 3

SELECT  A.areaKey AS AreaKey, 
        A.areaID AS AreaID,
        T.value AS CurrentValue,
        T.trnDateTime AS RecordedDateTime

FROM Areas A, Buildings B, Transactions T

WHERE   @buildingKey = B.buildingKey AND 
        B.buildingKey = A.buildingKey AND
        T.areaKey = A.areaKey AND
        T.trnDateTime IN (SELECT MAX(T.trnDateTime)
                                  FROM Transactions T
                                  GROUP BY T.areaKey)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you... 
I've edited your answer to match the table definitions given by me at the top of the question. (I edited what I have tried also.) 
Hopefully, this will make the question more generic and easy to understand for everyone else.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you lastest area for every building.

```
(PARTITION BY B.BuildingKey, a.areaKey ORDER BY T.TransactionDateTime DESC) RowID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  A.areaKey AS AreaKey, 
        A.areaID AS AreaID,
        T.value AS CurrentValue,
        T.trnDateTime AS RecordedDateTime                   
FROM Areas A JOIN Buildings B ON B.buildingKey = A.buildingKey 
             JOIN Transactions T ON T.areaKey = A.areaKey 
WHERE @buildingKey = B.buildingKey AND EXISTS (
                                       SELECT 1
                                       FROM Transactions T2
                                       WHERE T.areaKey = T2.areaKey
                                       GROUP BY T2.areaKey
                                       HAVING MAX(T2.trnDateTime) = T.trnDateTime
                                               )
```